# Looking for a smart pointer which will copy the underlying resource when copying the smart pointer itself

Tags: c++, vector, smart-pointers

**Motivation**

Imagining that there is a very large class `A`, and I wanna store it in a vector and I also want the vector to be copyable. Thus, smart pointer like `std::shared_ptr` and `std::unique_ptr` would not be nice choices. I know I could store objects of `A` in `std::vector<A>` directly. But as I said, `A` is a very large class. And since elements of `std::vector<A>` reside continuously in memory, there is a big chance that `std::vector<A>` needs to reallocate memory if I update it frequently. So, I need a "smart pointer" (let's say `copyable_ptr`) which will copy the underlying resource when copying the smart pointer itself. Then I could use `std::vector<copyable_ptr<A>>` to manage objects of `A`.

Here is a snippet template class of `copyable_ptr`:

```
template <typename T> class copyable_ptr {
  public:
    explicit copyable_ptr(T *p) : p(p) {}
    copyable_ptr(copyable_ptr const &rhs) : p(new T(*rhs.p)) {}
    copyable_ptr(copyable_ptr &&rhs) : p(rhs.p) { rhs.p = nullptr; }
    ~copyable_ptr() { delete p; }
    copyable_ptr &operator=(copyable_ptr rhs) {
        swap(rhs);
        return *this;
    }
    void swap(copyable_ptr &rhs) {
        using std::swap;
        swap(p, rhs.p);
    }
    T &operator*() const { return *p; }
    T *operator->() const { return &this->operator*(); }

    /* other members */

  private:
    T *p;
};

template <typename T>
inline void swap(copyable_ptr<T> &lhs, copyable_ptr<T> &rhs) {
    lhs.swap(rhs);
}
```

**Question**

Is there similar class that I can use directly or should I write my own or Is there any other appropriate solutions to store big class in container?

**Edit**

I think I should explain myself more clearly. `A` is a very large class, and I wanna use `std::vector` to manage objects of `A`. Basically, there are four options to do the job:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<A>> a1;    // #1
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<A>> a2;    // #2
std::vector<A *> a3;    // #3
std::vector<A> a4;    // #4
```

I do not want to share objects of `A`, which makes #1 inappropriate. The vector will not be copyable in #2, and I have to take care of memory management manually
in #3. So, only #4 lefts.

However, what I don't like about #4 is when size of `a4` reaches its capacity, reallocating happens. Double size of `a4` will be reserved (as I said, `A` is a very large class, isn't it inappropriate to reserve so much continuous memory in heap just for potential usage?). And What's worse is we perhaps need to move every single element of `a4` to the newly allocated memory from old memory location. Another backward of #4 that I forgot to mention when I asked the question is it's not polymorphic support.

So, if I use `std::vector<copyable_ptr<A>>` to manage objects of `A`, all the problems I mentioned above seems be handled properly. All you need is a well designed `copyable_ptr` class, and that's what I'm looking for.

Comment: I don't see how having this `copyable_ptr` is any advantage in the end.  The space for these objects needs to be allocated somewhere.

Comment: @GuyGreer Yes, the space is still needs to be allocated anyway, but the space for objects of `A` needs not to be continuous in heap, only the cheap `copyable_ptr` does. (if I'm not thinking wrong that `std::vector` puts all its elements together in heap)

Comment: Are you trying to do this just to save time on vector resizes? It sounds like you'd just lose that time to the extra allocation needed for each element and the extra layer of indirection for accesses.

Comment: Have you considered `std::deque<A>` ? You seem rather stuck on the `std::vector` despite its specific drawbacks.

Comment: There isn't any in the standard. You need to look up third party implementations.

Comment: Perhaps you could use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_container.html `ptr_vector` instead of `vector` ?

Comment: `explicit copyable_ptr(T *p) : p(p) {}` isn't correct, because your class will not take ownership of `*p`. You should do `explicit copyable_ptr(T *p) : p(new T(*p)) {}` instead.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is such a thing: it's called the class itself.

The whole purpose of a smart pointer is to provide a reference-counted handle for an object, that can be passed around, without copying the underlying object, and automatically destroy the object when the reference count goes down to 0, and the last smart pointer referencing the object goes out of scope, and it gets destroyed (with certain variations of reference-counting semantics between `shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, et al).

If you want to have some kind of a pointer to an object that copies it, when copying the pointer, you don't need a pointer for that. Just use the object directly, by value. Every time you copy it, you're guaranteed to copy the object, by definition.

Having some kind of pointer, around, adds absolutely nothing of value. You want to use the object directly, copy it when needed, etc... Just use the object.

Comment: It can add value.  Lets say the function that needs to do the copy is 3 levels down.  Passing the value down will take 3 copies to the stack.  Using a pointer would make 3 pointer copies to the stack, which is almost certainly smaller and faster.  Although I think I'd avoid such a concept just because its so unusual it would be more likely to be a cause of bugs then of value.

Comment: @GabeSechan Well, with your proposal, using a pointer would make 3 pointer copies on the stack *and each of those would make a full object copy*.

Comment: @Sam appreciate for your answer. Maybe I haven't explained myself clearly. What I wanna do is avoiding large objects resides continuously in heap (eg. when I use `std::vector<A>`). I know if i use `std::vector<copyable_ptr<A>>`, more construction work will be done, but `copyable_ptrt<A>` is much smaller than `A` at least. So that, objects of `copyable<A>` will resides continuously in heap but objects of `A` will not.

Comment: @Carousel: "avoiding large objects resides continuously in heap" - why would you want to avoid that?

Comment: I think I see the use case: If the object were 1MB in size ("A is a very large class") and he has 10K of them he needs 10GB of contiguous memory.  If the app adds these things to the vector as it reads them from disk it will reallocate and at some point the 8GB vector will need to double its size and the vector will try to allocate another 16GB of memory in order to expand - but lets say he only has 20GB of memory so it can't do that.  But if his vector had pointer type objects inside and was reallocated it wouldn't need more memory than he actually has on the machine.

Comment: Well it's possible a vector isn't the right data structure at all then, and a list is better

Comment: @JerryJeremiah - this is what `std::vector::reserve()` is for.

Comment: This thread has been very helpful to me in order to  implement polymorphic behavior:  I have a class `Class` that has a polymorphic pointer `Base*` to access one of several derived classes (`DerivedA`, `DerivedB`). When I create a `std::vector<Class>`, I need to be sure Class copies correctly. Default implementation will copy the pointer, so the first destruction of Class will delete `DerivedA`/`DerivedB` leaving me with a segfault. Replacing the pointer `Base*` with `copyable_ptr<Base>` works pefectly. I can't reserve in advance and the resources DerivedA/DerivedB can not be shared.

Comment: Late to the party but I just ran into a good use case for this: recursive types (in my case a JSON value).  I want to hold a pointer to a std::unordered_map<string, JSONValue> but have it copied like normal.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such smart pointer in the standard library. Your copyable_ptr seems to do the job. I've used such things in the past, though for polymorphic classes instead of just really big classes.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly the answer to question, but if this:

> However, what I don't like about #4 is when size of a4 reaches its capacity, reallocating happens.

is your main concern and if your are Ok with storing your classes in non-contiguous memory with slightly slower direct access by index, you can use `std::deque` instead of `std::vector`.